# Gilbert original paper (1955) reference

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, variational-principle, specific-reference

I'm looking for the Gilbert's original paper where he derives the gyromagnetic  Landau Lifshitz Gilbert (LLG) equation of motion from a variational principle.

Most of the people cite:

> Gilbert, Thomas L. "A Lagrangian formulation of the gyromagnetic equation of the magnetization field." Phys. Rev. 100 (1955): 1243.

So I've asked my library to retrieve it and... surprise! This page (1243) shows only a paragraph referencing something like a session in a conference, not a paper!

[Physical Review Journals Archive, Volume 100, Issue 4, November 1955](https://journals.aps.org/pr/issues/100/4)

I guess my expectations were too high (you know, some equations, maybe more than one paragraph...)

Does anyone know the correct reference then?

Comment: You probably need to supply a proper reference, at the very least the precise title.

Comment: This post [Landau Lifshitz Gilbert equation](https://mogadalai.wordpress.com/tag/landau-lifshitz-gilbert-equation/) may be of use?

Comment: @Farcher, yes, a really curious case. An excellent find!

Comment: I don't have Gilbert's reference, but a clear presentation of Gilbert's equation and assumptions is gven by Wegrowe and Ciornei in the following article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6782v1

Comment: Some background: http://mogadalai.wordpress.com/2007/10/11/the-case-of-the-curious-reference/amp/

Comment: So then, the citation is only an abstract (as in @Farcher link) nothing to do, then what is the reference of the full paper?

Comment: @BobJacobson Our two articles are the same but resident on different sites!

Comment: @Kaletho It seems that the closest match is "Armor Research Foundation Project No. A059, Supplementary Report, May 1, 1956", which appears to be some kind of technical report rather than a journal paper.

Comment: @Anyon, you are right, yet I have no access to it, and as it is pointed out in Farcher and Bob's links (which are the same), it seems to be an unpublished work.

Answer (score 2):

Gilbert cites himself in:

> Gilbert, Thomas L. "A phenomenological theory of damping in
>   ferromagnetic materials." IEEE Transactions on Magnetics 40.6 (2004):
>   3443-3449.

as:

> T. L. Gilbert and J. M. Kelly, “Anomalous rotational damping in fer-
>   romagnetic sheets,” in Conf. Magnetism and Magnetic Materials, Pitts-
>   burgh, PA, June 14–16, 1955. NewYork: American Institute ofElectrical
>   Engineers, Oct. 1955, pp. 253–263.

In the acknowledgments of the former he recognizes:

> "This paper is a condensed version of chapters I–III of my Ph.D.
>   thesis in which a new equation for the damped motion of the
>   magnetization field in a ferromagnet was derived (...)"

So I guess the thesis is the "original paper" and the 2004 IEEE paper reference should be used to help people looking for easy access to the derivation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

According to a previous comment

> "This paper is a condensed version of chapters I–III of my Ph.D.
>   thesis in which a new equation for the damped motion of the
>   magnetization field in a ferromagnet was derived (...)".

Please find here the Thomas L. Gilbert  [dissertation](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/saslow/TLGilbertDissertation.pdf). In the dissertation you can find the Gilbert research work regarding "a Lagrangian formulation of the gyromagnetic equation of the magnetization field"